# Using Git for syncing between multiples computers

Tags: git

I have multiples computers where I work (office, home, etc.). Some people told me to use git to sync the project between different computers, that will lead to commits like `git commit -m "goint to other pc"`  worth it?.

I'm not an advanced user of git, but I can't stop thinking that using git that way is an abuse of git or I'm just wrong?.

Comment: I'm using `git` this way routinely. I prefer to *conventionally* have *one* machine (perhaps some server on  http://github.com/ ...) play the role of the "master" `git` server for my project.

Comment: It's certainly an *abuse*. It may or may not be a *misuse* depending on your needs.

Comment: If you type a few words describing the diff instead of "going to other pc" then it won't lead to commits like that. The commit message should describe what changed, not why you decided to commit.

Comment: @TobiaTesan yeah, abuse represent better what I meant.

Comment: Then yes. That's not what `git` was meant for and I'm not sure it's a good idea either, but there's no law preventing you to do it. You have considered `rsync` instead, right?

Comment: @TobiaTesan yeah, is just some kind of *purist* question. But I think Chris comment is convincing me.

Comment: @Icjury: just to be clear: do you want a glorified backup system or a sane DVCS workflow? `git` can do the former, but it's designed for the latter. In the latter case you would *not* do what you set to do - and the commit message is only the tip of the iceberg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syncing between the two (or more) machines is something that sort of just happens when you're working with Git in general.

I would recommend using GitHub or BitBucket as your primary (origin) project repo.

From any machine that you work from, you would fetch/merge (pull) any changes that have happened on the primary repo.  Then you can do whatever you're doing from that machine, and when you're done you push those changes back up to the primary repo so that other developers (or yourself) from other machines can pull those changes and work accordingly.

Following this manner keeps everything in sync.  Also, when properly adding commit messages you won't have to make a "moving to other machine" commit.  You would simply pull all the commits in general to the other machine so that it matches.

Comment: And what happens in the case that changes done so far break the code?. Understand I can make a better commit message. But that is using git for something isn't designed for? Should try to avoid that? or it just doesn't matters?

Comment: Again, while it's not necessarily designed specifically as a sync product, following its procedures sort of does that on its own.  If merging code changes causes a problem you will get a merge conflict.  This will then allow you to see the conflicting code so that you can keep what needs kept and get rid of anything else.  I highly recommend you read up on Git in general, or better yet, watch the video series that Lynda.com provides for Git Essential Training.